# How to insert Vertical adsense ad space to my webpage?

Tags: html, css, adsense

How can  I create vertical space with div or something on my webpage for a google adsense ads, I would like to add vertical adsense ads  to the left and right of the table, see the image below:
https://ibb.co/LNg52NJ

and you can see the live version here or to inspect the code:
https://translatesubtitles.com/browse_subtitle.php

This is the table code:

```
<div class="row">
  <table id="example" data-order='[[ 0, "desc" ]]' class="table table-striped " style="width:100%">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th style="display: none">ID</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Language</th>
        <th>Author</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
      <?php
            include("sad.php");
            $query = "SELECT * FROM me order by id DESC";
            $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

            if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){

                while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){

                    ?>
        <tr>
          <td style="display: none"><?php echo $row['id']; ?></td>
          <td><a href="ed.php?id=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>"><?php echo $row['name']; ?></a></td>
          <td><?php echo $row['language']; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $row['author']; ?></td>
        </tr>

      <?php }} ?>

    </tbody>

  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use bootstrap column system and add code like this:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-3"><!-- ad sense --></div>
        <div class="col-sm-6"><!-- your table content --></div>
        <div class="col-sm-3"><!-- ad sense --></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: and please if you can just share the code  how can I increase width of the <div class="col-sm-6"><!-- your table content --></div>

Comment: I recommend to take a look at the bootstrap reference ([link](https://getbootstrap.com/)). `col-md-6` means that the div will take 6/12 of parents width.